# Python - scikit-learn: how to specify a validation subset in decision and regression trees?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to build decision trees and regression trees with Python. I am using sci-kit, but am open to alternatives.

What I don't understand about this library is whether a training and a validation subset can be provided, so that the library builds the model on the training subset, tests it on the validation and stops splitting based on some rules (typically when additional splits don't result in better performance on the validation subset- this prevents overfitting).
For example, this is what the JMP software does (http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Validation_2.shtml#1016975).

I found no mention of how to use a validation subset in the official website (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), nor on the internet.

Any help would be most welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Sklearn separates the cross-validation tools from the classifiers, which is a more elegant way of doing things, I think. See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly rich set of cross validation routines and examples in the [scikit learn cross validation section of the userguide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Note that lots of progress seems to have been made in cross validation between SK-Learn version 0.14 and 0.15, so I recommend upgrading to 0.15 if you haven't already.

As jme notes in his comment, some of the cross validation capability has also been incorporated into the grid search and pipeline capabilities of SK-learn.

For completeness in answering your question, here is simple example, but more advanced k-fold, leave-one-out, leave-p-out, shuffle-split, etc. are all available:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris.data.shape, iris.target.shape
((150, 4), (150,))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(iris.data,
                                                                     iris.target,
                                                                     test_size=0.4,
                                                                     random_state=0)

X_train.shape, y_train.shape
((90, 4), (90,))
X_test.shape, y_test.shape
((60, 4), (60,))

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)                           
0.96...
```

I hope this helps... Good luck!

Comment: Here, also is an example of [recursive feature elimination](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html) using a support vector classifier that would be easy to switch to a decision tree.

Comment: That's very useful, but I'm afraid it's not quite what I had in mind - or, if it is, I am confused. I'd like to replicate this JMP feature: <http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Partition_Method.shtml#1036390>

>When you click the Go button, the platform performs repeated >splitting until the validation R-Square is better than what the >next 10 splits would obtain.

In other words, I would like some stopping-pruning rule to be based on the performance of the model on the out-of-sample (test/validation/whatever we want to call it) dataset.

Comment: Instead, if I understand correctly, the examples above show how to assess the performance out-of-sample, not to prune the model based on the performance of the out-of-sample. I also note that here: <http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html> it says: "pruning (not currently supported)"

Comment: In essence, what you are looking for is a lot like a [random forests regressor/classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), which SK-Learn does have.  I know you may be looking for an apples to apples equivalent of JMP, but you may want to check it out.  A random forest is a meta estimator that fits a number of decision tree classifiers on various sub-samples of the dataset and use averaging to improve the predictive accuracy and control over-fitting.

Comment: not quite. However, I guess I can code a stopping rule similar to JMP's myself:
Say I start with max_depth = 4. I check the score of the tree on the out of sample. Then I increase max_depth until the score on the out of sample doesn't increase any more.
mytree.fit(x_train,y_train)
mytree.score(x_test,y_test)

Comment: To help put things into context, what I am looking at is to what extent data from one group can be used to predict data from a yet unobserved group. E.g. using New York data to predict Los Angeles: all of the LA data would be in the test/validation/out of sample dataset, and the performance of the tree trained on NY should be assessed on LA